# Spring run code on new connection of user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, events

Is there a possibility to execute a method when a new user connects to the server?
Is there a Bean, Service, or a Listener I can use?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you see as a `new` user? When someone registers for the first time? When it is the first time that the IP requests your site? Or when a new session is started?

Comment: I see it in the point of a connection. Example: everytime a user visits the website I want to run a specific function. Not like a 'new' user that just registered

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Interceptor` for this, it will run for every request to your website. You can define an interceptor like:

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        // Do something here
        return true;
    }
}
```

A great blog post which explains this in detail can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor)

Comment: This does only work in Spring MVC right? Is it possible to achieve this without Spring MVC because I use another framework for that

Comment: @Johnny, which framework is that? Because it highly depends on the inner workings of the framework. And yes this is specific for spring

Comment: I'm using Vaadin 10

Comment: @Johnny, I assume you are combining spring-boot with Vaadin flow? Since you tagged the question as spring-boot

Comment: Yes. It's my first project with Spring and Vaadin and I'm a little bit confused...

Comment: @Johnny, based on this link: https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-basic.html I expect it to work in your project too. The setup is 90% the same as a regular spring boot application and uses exactly the same classes, so I expect that the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` still ties to the same behaviour.  So if you put this class in your application and follow the rest of the tutorial from my answer I expect it to work. If it does not, please let me know :)